# how to read binary data ¬ ( &#x2;) in xml using c# generated by windows

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008

how to read binary data ¬ ( ) in xml using c# generated by windows . 
I am trying to access the List out the registry keys in the windows reg . 
There are binary data popping up in string value . I am able to serialize it using xml serialization ,to (&#x2) but I am not able to de-serialize it back ? 
Can anyone explain me what is going wrong and why ? help me to fix this one . 
Many thanks :))) 
Error while reading is:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message="There is an error in XML document (235, 28)."
>   Read From file:

```
public diagnostics readregkey(diagnostics diagnostics, string filename)
{
    diagnostics dia = null;
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = 
        new System.IO.StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = 
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(diagnostics));
        dia = x.Deserialize(sr) as diagnostics;
    }
    return dia;
}
```

Write to file:

```
public static void  WriteRegKey(diagnostics diagnostics, string filename)
{
    diagnostic.regKeys.Add(key(Registry.LocalMachine, sKeyGravitas));
    diagnostic.regKeys.Add(key(Registry.CurrentUser, sKeyGravitas));
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = 
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename,false, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = 
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(diagnostics));
        x.Serialize(sw, diagnostics);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you any example code / error messages we can use to help you?

Comment: Show us your exact code for serializing it out, and later back in again? This appears not to be an isolated problem: http://marc.info/?l=xalan-dev&m=98865838020552&w=2

Comment: Isn't this the same as your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631122/how-to-read-and-write-in-xml ??

Answer (score 3):

XML files cannot represent every character, even using the `&#x;` notation.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

XML 1.1, which is not widely used, can support all characters except NUL.

But for 0x0002, expressing it as `&#x2;` in XML simply isn't the right format.

The usual way of handling embedded binary data is to convert it to base-64.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also and, in order to help the next one, I leave here what I used to solve it.

As lavinio said, XML cannot represent every character. Therefore, using the table he provided I wrote a method, very similar to another answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/641632/2315604, that I call before before serializing.

```
private string XmlCharWhiteList(string p)
{
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char c in p)
        {
            if (c == 0x0009 || c == 0x000A || c == 0x000D ||
                (c >= 0x0020 && c <= 0xD7FF) ||
                (c >= 0xE000 && c <= 0xFFFD))
                stringBuilder.Append(c);
            else
                stringBuilder.Append(' ');
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

And, since .NET 4.0, you can use `XmlConvert.IsXmlChar` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.isxmlchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx